# How can I have a class dispose and an inherited class dispose both run?

Tags: c#

I have this base class that my controllers are using:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    protected JavaCertContext db = new JavaCertContext();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

In a couple of my controllers I also need to dispose of some other objects like this:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    {
        if (disposing && _userManager != null)
        {
            _userManager.Dispose();
            _userManager = null;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

In these controllers how can I ensure that **both** the controller Dispose and the inherited Dispose that it inherits get executed ?

Comment: You're calling `base.Dispose()` so why would you assume they wouldn't both be disposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's precisely what the `base.Dispose(disposing);` call is doing, i.e. calling the dispose method of the base class!

Answer (score -2):

Follow the [Dispose pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P) correctly. It will make sure that the child dispose is called first followed by the parent's dispose.

```
 public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
        protected JavaCertContext db = new JavaCertContext();

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    public class ChildController : BaseController
    {
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_userManager != null)
                {
                    _userManager.Dispose();
                    _userManager = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }

    public class ApiController
    {
        private volatile bool _isDiposed;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_isDiposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            Dispose(true);

            _isDiposed = true;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            if (isDisposing)
            {
                //Dispose stuff.
            }
        }
    }

    public class JavaCertContext
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify how his implementation differs from a correct implementation?